# eclipse template two newName

Tags: java, eclipse, templates, eclipse-templates

I'm trying to write an Eclipse template to generate two variables with non-conflicting names.

When I use the template twice in the same method, the second `matcherVar` has the same name as the first `matcherVar` giving a naming conflict that I was trying to avoid.

**Incorrect output:**

```
Pattern patternVar = Pattern.compile(patternString);
Matcher matcherVar = patternVar.matcher(matcherString); // correct matcherVar

Pattern patternVar0 = Pattern.compile(patternString);
Matcher matcherVar = pattern.matcher(matcherString); // wrong, instead: matcherVar0
```

As you can see I have incorrectly generated a conflicting name running the template twice.

**Current Template: (newline characters and comments have been added for readability)**

```
${:include(java.util.regex.Pattern, java.util.regex.Matcher)}

// compile Pattern object with patternString
${pattern_type:newType(java.util.regex.Pattern)} 
    ${patternVar:newName(pattern_type)} 
        = ${pattern_type.compile(${patternString:var(String)});

// create Matcher object from the Pattern and matchingString
${matcher_type:newType(java.util.regex.Matcher)}
    ${matcherVar:newName(matcher_type)} // <------------------------- **wrong**
        = ${patternVar}.matcher(${matchingString:var(String)});
```

**Note:** What is strange is that after running the template 3 or more times in the same method, the generated name does not conflict so this might be a bug with Eclipse.